# Book about a human who travels to an alien planet to be a teacher

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I'm trying to find a book about a human who travels to an alien planet to be a teacher. Kind of like an American traveling to Asia to teach English, but teaching aliens instead. The human deals with the culture shock of living in a new place, trying to relate to the alien students, that kind of thing. I think it was released in the early 2000s. Not much to go on I know, but that's about all I remember.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you actually read this? And, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: Sorry don't remember anything about the cover. I think I read it about 2005.

Answer (score 2):

This book is *[Angry Young Spaceman](https://jimmunroe.net/category/books/angry-young-spaceman)* by Jim Munroe.

> Sam’s going to another planet to teach English, where he hopes to earn enough creds to pay off his student loan and maybe buy a jetpack. He’s not entirely comfortable with spreading the English virus but it beats working for the power brokers on Earth, and Octavia is a dreamy underwater planet populated by eight-armed beings.
>
> He ends up learning more than teaching. From Mr. Zik, a singer of melancholy songs. From a boxy robot named 9/3. And from Jinya, whose undulating tentacles make Sam forget all about human legs.

https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?388142

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this is the correct answer?